# I want to apply toggle btn in form,When Device size is small than toogle should b appear and form will be collapse through toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Search
                
                
                    
                        
                                      
                                        
                                          
                                            
                                              From
                                              
                                            
                                          
                                          
                                            
                                              To
                                              
                                            
                                          
                                        
                                      
                                      
                                        
                                          
                                            
                                              
                                                Departing
                                                
                                              
                                            
                                            
                                              
                                                Returning
                                                
                                              
                                            
                                            
                                              
                                                Passngers
                                                
                                                  1
                                                  2
                                                  3
                                                  4
                                                  5
                                                  6
                                                  7
                                                  8
                                                  9
                                                  10
                                                  11
                                                  12
                                                  13
                                                  14
                                                
                                              
                                            
                                            
                                               
                                              Search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a form and write the collapse button code from getbootstrap.com and now put a hidden-md class on that button so that, button will not appear on large and medium devices.But visible on small devices.

Now perform toggle event by applying an id to form and button.